# Does pedaling a bicycle produce a leftward torque?

Tags: vectors, torque

If toque is defined by
$$
\mathbf{\tau} = \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F}
$$
and we apply a force to the pedal as shown below, wouldn't there be a leftward force via torque about the crankshaft?  Is it usually just negligible, and that's why I can't remember feeling it?  Also, when riding with clips, it is possible to pull up on the back stroke, which would produce simultaneous left and right torques (one for either foot) - maybe only pro cyclists feel such a force?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing torques and forces.

Forces can be thought as the origin of acceleration, which is what you feel under your foot when you push the pedal. This is given by Newton's law:
$$ m\ \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{F}$$

Torques are measuring how strongly a force, applied on a rigid body is making the body rotate. In the example you gave, the torque is pointing perpendicularly to the plane of the bicycle: the torque is accelerating the rotation of the pedals. The torques are appearing in equations linking the angular momentum $\mathbf{L} = m\ \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v}$ to the torques of the forces:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}\dot{\mathbf{L}}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \tau, $$ where $\tau$ is the sum of the torques and $\mathbf{L}$ is the angular momentum of the rigid body (the pedal).

Comment: -1 Torque is a force. Clarify.

Comment: No, a torque is the moment of a force. You can see it is not the same using homogeneity. While forces are expressed in Newton ($\mathrm{kg.m.s^{-2}}$), torques are expressed in Newton meters ($\mathrm{kg.m^2.s^{-2}}$). A torque is only measuring how strong a force creates rotation but it doesn't measure linear momentum.

Comment: Well thought. I didn't think it thoroughly. +1 again (if I could).

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, I clarified my answer for the OP.